# Why performLongClick() doesn't get called when I long press the phone

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a customer view that supports dragging. I want to disable dragging after long click is triggered, so I override performLongClick() to record long click.

```
    @Override
    public boolean performLongClick(float x, float y) {
        boolean ret = super.performLongClick(x, y);
        mHasPerformedLongPress = true;
        return ret;
    }
```

But I found that this function was not called when I long press the phone, even OnLongClickListener has responded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood what was supposed to happen.
According to the doc : [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#performLongClick(float,%20float)), the function performLongClick calls the view's OnLongClickListener, even though no real long click happened.

This function is not called when the user performs a long click.

Instead, the view's OnLongClickListener is called when the user long clicks it.
Whan you want to do is to override the OnLongClickListener and put your logic there :

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
myView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    boolean ret = super.onLongClick(v);
    mHasPerformedLongPress = true;
    return ret;
  }
});
```

Comment: Source codes of View in API 31 shows performLongClick() would get called when View handles long press. That confuses me. I  tested it on API 31 platform again and it works.  Perhaps old platform has different behaviors about this function.